# Please wrap the entire comment flag description in a `<label>` (making the entire text clickable)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, comment-flags, usability

Currently, in the [new comment flag modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/289905), when you want to select an option, you have to click either on the radio button, or on the top part of the description. This is because only the top part of the description is contained in a `<label>`.

This doesn’t match the behavior of the other older modals. I’d like the entire text to be clickable to select the corresponding radio button, instead of having to click on this rather thin strip.

This is a screenshot of the flag modal with the `<label>` being inspected. The bottom description should be part of the `<label>`, too, or perhaps in another `<label>` for the same radio button — whichever works best.

[image: Picture of the comment flag modal with the label element highlighted: not the entire text is contained within it]

### Other people requesting this feature

- For *older* flag modals, [a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226864/289905) similar to this one has been proposed in 2014.
- Before I asked my question, this has been requested in this comment (which I overlooked at first):

  > [feature-request] Can you make the flag option's subtext clickable? (Like in all other flag dialogs) – [Floern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164356/floern) [2018-07-31 21:27:57Z](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313433/did-the-comment-flag-dialog-change-will-there-be-future-dialog-changes#comment1026899_313433)
- After my question, [E.P.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/184688/e-p)’s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313475/289905) to the question [“Did the comment flag dialog change? Will there be future dialog changes?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313433/289905) requested this feature.

Comment: Also requested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313475/184688) to the initial thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flag description will be clickable starting with the next production build.