# Increase clickable area in comment flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, comment-flags, usability, flag-dialog

The comment flag dialog [recently changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313433/160917).  A side effect of that change was to [reduce the size of the clickable area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313475/160917).  In particular, the clickable regions on the new flag dialog are pretty skinny, as shown in red below:

[image: current flag dialog]

This is frustrating, because it requires me to put my mouse in *just* the right place, which takes extra effort.

I wish the clickable regions were instead larger, so they included all of the text associated with the corresponding option, like this:

[image: a better flag dialog]

That would be better, because it would make it easier to select the option.  It would also match the way [other dialogs work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226864/160917) on this site.  Can this change be made?